# How can I test if the contents of a maven assembly dir are correct?

Tags: maven, testing, maven-assembly-plugin

I am building a complex server (tomcat) structure via assembly, containing libs, deployments, datasource settings ...

I would like to test the contents of the dir/zip before deployment making sure that everything is there, in the right location and with the correct filtered properties.

How can I apply (unit) tests that analyse the dir and assert that certain files exists and have the correct content?

Comment: Write an integration tests which binds to `integration-test` and check the content of the created zip which is created during the package phase? (It is not an unit tests it's an integration test)...Best would be to use [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. When integration-test runs after package, this will solve my problem. I would love to give you karma, so maybe just provide an answer that I can accept? Would be perfect if you would also give me a hint how I can access the files in target (they have the project.version in their path) in my AssemblyIT.

Comment: Why do you need to add libs to Tomcat ? Why not delivering them with your war file ? Do you need to create for different environments like dev,test,qa, prod?

Comment: We have a "legacy" target platform that defines a jndi datasource in the server.xml and therefore provides oracle driver in /lib. We want to simulate this target environment locally and for automatic testing without modifying the production wars.

Comment: why not using puppet for that? https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-tomcat

Comment: Definitely an option ... maven/assembly  was chosen because we already had it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to to create an integration test which runs after the package phase. This can handled via the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) which can be bound to `integration-test` phase. You need of course follow the naming conventions of the maven-failsafe-plugin.

To access the generated file you can use a system property which is given to maven-failsafe-plugin configuration. Like:

```xml
<systemPropertyVariables>
  <fileName>${project.build.finalName}</fileName>
  <folder>${project.build.outputDirectory}</folder>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

This will give the whole file name of the resulting artifact if you using a separate module to create those distribution artifact. I'm not 100% sure what about the classifier which is created based on the `<id>..</id>` in the assembly descriptor file.

The `folder` will give you the location where the artifacts are being created.

You might also being interested in the following [plugin](https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin).